# Django ORM filter by singular field name

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Is it possible to filter a model by some additional/singular version of field name?

For example, using model like (where `authors` is `CharField` which contains python-list, e.g. `['Johnny']`):

```
class Movie(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
actors = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

And query something like `Movie.objects.filter(input)`, where input is `<QueryDict: {'actor': ["['Johnny']", "['Pablo']"]}>`

Anyone has idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have made the models, you would need to save the actors as a String, for example `Johnny, Pablo`. Therefore, you would be able to make queries like `Movie.objects.all().filter(actors='Johnny, Pablo')`.

Usually, this should have been done with a [many-to-one relationship model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), letting you query specific objects, letting you query multiple actors or one natively.